# Compiling android .so library on visual studio error with android ndk 15c __signbit

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, android-ndk, clang

i was using android ndk 13b with visual studio 2017 and i got an update for android ndk 15c which added one error. I am also using new Clang 5.0 (before it was 3.8). This is the error :

> /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r15-release/ndk/sources/android/support/src/stdio/vfprintf.c(242):
>   error : undefined reference to '__signbit'

This is my verbose full response :

> 1>Android clang version 5.0.300080  (based on LLVM 5.0.300080)
>   1>Target: i686-none-linux-android 1>Thread model: posix
>   1>InstalledDir:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
>   1>Found candidate GCC installation:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android\4.9.x
>   1>Selected GCC installation:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x
>   1>Candidate multilib: .;@m32 1>Selected multilib: .;@m32 1>
>   "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld"
>   "--sysroot=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-23\arch-x86"
>   --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -shared -o "x86\Release\libPredictEngineMultiLang.so"
>   "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-23\arch-x86/usr/lib\crtbegin_so.o"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\lib\linux\i386"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/lib"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-23\arch-x86/usr/lib"
>   "-rpath-link=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-23\arch-x86\usr\lib"
>   "-rpath-link=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-23\arch-x86\usr\lib"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-23\arch-x86\usr\lib"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\i686-linux-android\4.9.x"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\x86"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\i686-linux-android\4.9.x"
>   "-LC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\x86"
>   --no-undefined -z relro -z now -z noexecstack "x86\Release\CharsetConverter.o" "x86\Release\CppSQLite3.o"
>   "x86\Release\PhonemConverterEN.o"
>   "x86\Release\PhonemConverterFR.o" "x86\Release\PhoneticEngineEN.o"
>   "x86\Release\PhoneticEngineFR.o" "x86\Release\PredictDb.o"
>   "x86\Release\PredictEngineEN.o" "x86\Release\PredictEngineFR.o"
>   "x86\Release\SearchEngineEN.o" "x86\Release\SearchEngineFR.o"
>   "x86\Release\sqlite3.o" "x86\Release\DictionaryEN.o"
>   "x86\Release\DictionaryFR.o" "x86\Release\PhonemEN.o"
>   "x86\Release\PhonemFR.o" "x86\Release\PredictEN.o"
>   "x86\Release\PredictFR.o"
>   "C:\Users\hhenry-garon\Downloads\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt-master\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt-master\openssl-1.0.2\x86\lib\libcrypto.a"
>   -landroid_support -lc++_static -lc++abi -landroid_support -lc++_static -lc++abi -llog -landroid -lgcc -ldl -lc -lgcc -ldl "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-23\arch-x86/usr/lib\crtend_so.o"
>   1>/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r15-release/ndk/sources/android/support/src/stdio/vfprintf.c(242):
>   error : undefined reference to '__signbit' 1>clang.exe : error :
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am compiling in x86 a android library .so with Clang 5.0 on visual studio 2017. I only read that maybe i can add a no-stdio configuration but i have no idea where to do that in visual studio 2017.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issues with Android NDK 15c on Visual studio 2017.
I was using LLVM static and i changed for GNU static, everything works now.

Thanks to microsoft (not)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into this - I resolved this by adding "m" to the "Library Dependencies" in the linker flags in vs. It seems like libc++ has a dependency on the c math library. Functions like printf, sprintf etc are using __signbit.

Comment: fixed it for both ARM and x86. For ARM64/x64 it is not required.